# Get properties of a type

Tags: typescript, prisma

I can't find a way to lookup in runtime whether a certain property exists on a type. Like so (pseudocode)

```
import { MyType } from '@prisma/client';

MyType.hasProperty("foo") // true/false

MyType.allProperties() // ["foo", "bar", "stuff"]
```

Does anyone know a good solution? Thank you in advance !

Comment: As a purely typescript question this is not possible, but maybe it can be done with the Prisma object?  I’m adding the Prisma tag.

Comment: I've definitely wished I could do this before, but the philosophy of TypeScript has always been that the typing system is a compile-time only thing, with no impact on the run-time environment. It would be great if you could optionally export some sort of run-time object associated with a type containing info about that type, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Types don't exist at runtime. But you can still inspect objects that exist at runtime. You can use the `in` operator to check if an object contains a particular property, and you can use use `Object.keys(someObj)` to get all keys on an object as an array.

```
const foo = { a: 123, b: 'bar' }
'a' in foo // true
Object.keys(foo) // ['a', 'b']
```

What you *cannot* do is get this info from a type or interface. It must be a real object that exists at runtime.